# Sorting the column depending on other column

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to sort column, let's say I have Name,Account_Number column and Account_Number should depend on Name column.

```
Name  Account_Number Relationship Sex
John  101            M            M
John  102            M            M
Mary  102            J            F
Seth  102            J            F
John  103            M            M
Joy   99             M            M
Eles  99             J            F
Joy   100            M            M
Sarn  98             M            M
Sarn  106            M            M
Mary  106            J            F
```

In the following example, John has 3 accounts, but one of his account has 2 partners(Mary and seth).

How could i archive such a thing in oracle? Please help.

Comment: And what should the final order be? It's not clear, I vote to close this question.

Comment: @krokodilko I don't think my question would be that hard becoz someone already provided me the answer, but thank for your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JOIN table it self, select only sub and order by main query

```
SELECT s.name, s.acc, s.rel, s.sex FROM public.cif m
JOIN (SELECT name, acc, rel, sex FROM public.cif) s ON m.acc = s.acc
WHERE m.rel = 'M'
ORDER BY m.name, m.acc
```

Comment: Your solution works like a charm. Do we have any analytical function aside joining itself? On the top of that, I can use temp_table as reusable sub-query with the above solution.

Comment: I'm glad it help, you may use temp_table but you still join and multiple query. isn't it?

Comment: Yes I am. But if we have another way, that would save the performance and time.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what result you are expecting.

You can use order by clause with highest priority column first then the second column.

If above table is what you are expecting then below query will do that.

```
select * from <tableName> order by Account_Number,Name;
```

Comment: I just want to list all accounts, but this case john has 3 account, but one of his have 2 partner(seth and mary). Can we do that in oracle sql ?